# div tag should not take up space

Tags: css

#decoration extend a bit outside of #wrapper. The problem is that if the browser viewport is 910px a vertical scroll bar appears.

How do I make it so that #decoration to not occupy space so the vertical scroll bar do not appear.

**EDIT:**

Check out this link to see what I want. Just in such a way no vertical scroll bar is there.

http://jsfiddle.net/HLqwN/

Using overflow:hidden will clip part of #decoration so that do not work.

```
<head>
    <style>
        #wrapper {
            width: 900px;
            position: relative;
        }
        #decoration {
            position: absolute;
            width: 542px;
            height: 126px;
            top: 0;
            left: 660px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img id="decoration" src="/images/decoration.png" alt="" title="" />
        <div id="content">
            Some content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you setup a demo or screenshot of your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* set `overflow: hidden` as the other answers are suggesting.

However, a "decoration" image should not be an `<img>`, it should be a CSS `background-image`.

Like this:

```
#wrapper {
    height: 126px;
    background: #ccc url(http://dummyimage.com/542x126/f0f/fff) 660px 0 no-repeat
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/rdSJH/

Comment: I think I have asked my question poorly. Here is a link to clarify: http://jsfiddle.net/HLqwN/

Comment: You're right - your question was a little unclear. However, after your clarification, I think I understand. I added an "outer wrapper", that has `overflow: hidden`, and `min-width: 500px`. Now, the overhanging part of the "decoration" cannot cause the scrollbar to appear. See: http://jsfiddle.net/HLqwN/1/

Answer (score 4):

if it is a decorative image, perhaps you should use it as a background image on the wrapper rather than in HTML source, you can still position it 660px left and it will not then cause a content scroll bar as it's not content.

```
#wrapper {
   width: 900px;
   position: relative;
   background: url(background.png) no-repeat 660px 0;
}
```

**[update after your clarification]**

OK so you want the decoration to overlap the wrapper if there's space available to do so, like a pop-out?

is so try this, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUWLC/9/)

notes: the span holding the background image should be outside the wrapper,  no width on the span use your left co-ordinate and right: 0; or whatever margin from the right you might like, and still use the image as a background image. the span can sit down the bottom of your HTML out of the way

Answer (score 1):

You could use overflow: hidden; on your wrapper

Comment: Won't work. Part of #decoration will be clipped where #wrapper right border stops

Answer (score 1):

You might want to wrap a div around the decoration image and set `overflow:hidden` on that. Setting `overflow:hidden` on your wrapper might cause other content to be clipped depending on your layout.

If it's just a decoration you should try doing it with a background image though, then you don't have to worry about the clipping.